# reading dates from process substitution using awk. Issue with field separator, splitting tokens incorrectly

Tags: bash, date, read

I have the following code, thanks to @Janis for the help with the process substitution.

Also, apologies for creating a new question, I haven't received any recent replies on the thread of my previous one, I can't add a bounty to that one, and I'm really stuck. I hope it's ok

The dates on the html pulled with curl request are this format: 2015-04-06 09:40:37

Two dates are being extracted with awk and assigned to the variables `new` and `old` respectively, but the strings are being split on white space within the date strings. I tried changing OFS to ',', but it was still splitting incorrectly.

```
IFS="," 
read dateStrNew dateStrOld < <(curl -k -q "$curl_call" | html2text | gawk '/Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }/Oldest Sequence/ \
 {old=$3" "$4}END {OFS=","; print new,old }')  //new = date, old = date
```

sample output with `IFS ','`
(newest = dateStrNew ; oldest = dateStrOld)

```
newest ,

oldest 

newest 1428350400

oldest 

newest ,

oldest 

newest 2015-04-07 06

oldest 29:29,2015-04-06 09:40:37

newest ,

oldest 

newest 2015-04-07 06

oldest 29:29,2015-04-06 09:40:37
```

`curl` request is `https://username:password@ip/report`

Two dates are contained within the html report, in this format: `2015-04-06 09:41:14`

So I am searching for "Newest Date" and "Oldest Date" within the html file, pulling the fields from that line containing the date, assigning the two fields to a variable. There are two dates, so two awk variables, newest and oldest

Comment: Could you include example output from `curl -k -q "$curl_call" | html2text | gawk '/Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }/Oldest Sequence/ \
 {old=$3" "$4}END {OFS=","; print new,old }'`?

Comment: It's hard to do clearly in comments, but 'newest', 'oldest' are debugging variables which should contain the string output, and then 'date' is once I've run the date command
first:   `newest ,
oldest 
date: invalid date' ,'
date: invalid date +%s`

Comment: second: `newest 2015-04-07 06
oldest 29:29,2015-04-06 09:40:37
date: extra operand 40'`

Comment: third: `newest ,
oldest 
date: invalid date ','`

Comment: Does that output make sense? Why are there error messages instead of dates? And please edit your question with the extra information (instead of adding comments). Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the output without the `read` command? See my first comment for the exact command; the idea here is to see what you're trying to interpret with `read`.

Comment: error messages instead of dates are because the date strings were not read correctly into the variables dateStrNew and dateStrOld.  I want the two variables in awk, new and old, to be sent out as two separate items and read as such into the two variables. But the strings are being split in the wrong place

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to show the actual output as it's sensitive info, hope I've given you enough

Comment: Not really, no... Does the exact command I listed in my first comment really reveal sensitive information?

Comment: `2015-01-14 17:11:11,2014-09-16 02:43:40`
This is the output without read. So the issue is definitely word splitting at the point of the read command. I wonder if something needs escaping or quoting?

Comment: I'm having to do this slightly differently as our server is offline, and it's strange I've been changing the IFS the whole time, but this is what has just happened. `read new old < <(cat testdata.txt |  gawk '/Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }/Oldest Sequence/ \
 {old=$3" "$4}END {OFS=","; print new,old }')` Same issue as above. `IFS=","read new old < <(cat testdata.txt |  gawk '/Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }/Oldest Sequence/ \
 {old=$3" "$4}END {OFS=","; print new,old }')` Output correct. The thing is, last line with the IFS is identical to my latest script,only difference cat file not curl

Comment: Also this using cat with an actual html file generated with the curl command works fine `IFS="," read newest oldest < <(cat curl_test.html | html2text | gawk '/Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }/Oldest Sequence/ \
 {old=$3" "$4}END {OFS=","; print new,old }')` There must be a bug in my script